# Sorting Grid data in JavaScript. Getting error in sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to sort a grid data which was obtained from a kendo grid

```
functionTableGrid = GetGridData("functionTable");
gridData = functionTableGrid.dataSource.data(); // getting the data
```

Fucnction for sorting and calling sort

```
function sortfunc(a,b) {        
    return a.Description < b.Description;
}
gridData.sort(sortfunc);
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: gridData.sort is not a function
```

I am not sure why its not working. I have posted my head here maybe there is some issue with the Head.

```
<head id="Head1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" ie="10">
<title> C&S </title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Styles/cs.Application.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Styles/kendo.common.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Styles/kendo.default.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="../JS/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.service.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.base.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.service.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.mappings.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.importexport.common.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.router.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.admin.workflows.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../JS/cs.admin.workflows.data.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<link id="SL_Style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chrome://imtranslator/content/css/translator.css">
<style type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</head>
```

Comment: What's this? `<style type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">`!

Comment: Do `console.log(gridData)` . actually your data is not an array

Comment: I'm pretty sure that gridData is not an Array istance, check what gridData constructor is.

Comment: So can you please guide me how to sort this grid data by description field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dataSource.data()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) returns an [`ObservableArray`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observablearray), which is different from a plain JavaScript array.

To get a regular JavaScript array, use the [`toJSON()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observablearray#methods-toJSON) method of the ObservableArray.